# Azure Search for SQL Server Blob Column

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search, azure-data-sync

I have a table `[Assets]` on Azure SQL Server with columns (Id, Name, Owner, Asset). The [Asset] column is varbinaryblob type that store PDF files.

I would like to use Azure Search to be able to search through the content of this column. Currently Azure Search can be directly used with Blob Store or exclusively for table store however I a am not able to find a solution for my scenario, Any help in terms of approach is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this seems helpfull :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers

Comment: Interesting! Have you considered 'just' uploading the documents to Azure Search also? This will have some impact to your current design, but might be easier to go with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Search SQL indexer doesn't support document extraction from varbinary/blob columns.

One approach would be to upload the file data into Azure blob storage and then use [Azure Search blob indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage).

Another approach is to use Apache Tika or iTextSharp to extract text from PDF in your code and then index it with Azure Search.

Comment: To extend on what Eugene stated, one option you could try for doing this is to use Azure Functions.   There is an example of how to do this PDF parsing from using Tika in [Azure Functions here](https://github.com/liamca/AzureSearch-AzureFunctions-CognitiveServices/tree/master/ApacheTika).   In this example it gets the PDF’s from Blob Storage, but you could switch this to get it from SQL.

Comment: Thank you Eugene, Liam for response.

Comment: Thank you @Eugene Shvets - MSFT , Liam for response. Could you please let me know if the following approach is Ok, I will go ahead and use Azure Blob Storage and utilize Metadata fields to for list fields on SharePoint. Azure Search can search on both Metadata and content hence that solves my  problem. are there any downsides of this approach?

Comment: Try it and let us know if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to create a SQL VM, sync your data on SQL Azure with the VM with SQL Data Sync, then sync data on the SQL VM with Azure Search as explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-sync-sql-server-data-with-azure-search/)?

Another option is to move your SQL Azure database to a SQL VM on Azure, then sync data on SQL VM with Azure Search as explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-to-sync-sql-server-data-with-azure-search/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be actually answering the question.

Comment: Agree with @Eugene Shvets - MSFT . the answer provide is a generic search approach, i was looking for alternatives to search both column data of primitive types and varbinary fields